# How to set the extent of an OpenLayers Map?

Tags: dictionary, zooming, openlayers, bounds, pan

I want to pan and zoom an `OpenLayers.Map` to a given `OpenLayer.Bounds`.

What is a quick way to do this action?

I want to see everything that is in the bounds on the map.

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try [OpenLayers.Map.zoomToExtent(OpenLayers.Bounds)](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.zoomToExtent) which will zoom to the passed in bounds and recenter the map.